# Redhat linux log of which user ran shutdown

Tags: linux

On a redhat production box someone just ran shutdown and I need to find the log file that specifically shows which user ran the "shutdown" command (and when would be nice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only root can run shutdown, hence that user was root.

Hopefully you enforce the use of `sudo` to run root commands. In that case, look in `/var/log/secure` to find out who did `sudo shutdown`.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how the command was executed, this can be a bit tricksome.

1. Check your sudo logs, they are using sudo right?!?
2. If run directly as root, see who else was logged in at the same time. Using the wtmp file through the `last` command may be helpful.
3. If they remotely logged in as root, check, again using `last` which address they logged in from and who was using that system at that time. Also, fix this so they can't log in remotely as root.
4. If logged in through the console, check your access logs to see who had physical access to the system at the time.

Comment: All of those options kind of work, but are really hard when there are 10+ people logged in. I'm hoping there is a clear log of " this user ran shutdown at this time" type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

`last|head`

Hopefully not too many admins are logged in at the same time as root.

Comment: Lots of people logged in

Comment: Directly as root, just before the shutdown?